# Why ngOnInit doesn't work if i open component from MatDialog?

Tags: angular

Why the component may get stuck after constructor? ngOnInit does not take a very long time to reach. If there is a random change to store, for example, then the component loading continues

If I declare like this:

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

everything is work. but if I do like this:

```
public show(someData:SomeData) {
    const config: MatDialogConfig = {
      hasBackdrop: true,
      data: {
        someData,
      },
    };
    this.matDialog.open(MyComponent, config);
  }
```

ngOnInit doesn't work. why?

Comment: How do you know ngOnInit doesn’t work? Can you post that component?

Comment: It can only happen in case of that the same 'MyComponent' is already in the DOM. and ngOnInit() only gets called when the component gets initialized for the first time only. @mzkrgkmay

Comment: @AakashKumar I'd be a little more specific and say that `MyComponent`'s `ngOnInit` method is only called once __per instance__ of `MyComponent` when __that instance__ is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `MyComponent.ngOnInit` will be called when you invoke c method. `MatDialog` will create this component in runtime in response to event which will call `show` method